# onBlur event function needed for my project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need help on javascript code for a project.

When a field(A) input value is onblur, I want a situation where the value will pass to an external php file (external.php) and the result computed in the backend external php file (external.php) should the value of another disabled input field(B). Putting in mind the for the internal HTML form action is (index.php).

Comment: googled before now ,i have tried some of the examples on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ but still not working.

Comment: @Kunle Please don't dump code blocks in comments, [edit] your question and update it with such info.

Comment: i have reposted what i wrote T J.

Comment: "i want a situation" OR event.

Comment: event, I mean to say, do you have any idea @black ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="inputA" onBlur="inputA();" id="spend" /><span id="feedback"></span>
<input type="text" name="inputB" id="receive" disabled="true"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function inputA(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','http://localhost/myproject/fetchvalueB.php?name='+document.getElementById['spend'].value,false);
xhr.send(null);
document.getElementById['feedback'].InnerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
</script>
```